# How do I add custom formatting to docx files generated in Pandoc?

Tags: docx, pandoc

How can I add custom formatting to docx files generated by [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) from, say, Markdown? For example, can I highlight text or center it? Can I restyle links, etc?

I know that I can change styles for default elements, like headings, by using a `--reference-doc` (generated with `pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx`), but I'd like to introduce additional styles.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are basically 3 ways to customize docx output in Pandoc:

1. [Mentioned in the question] Customize **default elements** (like headings and blockquotes) by editing the reference doc.
2. Customize **other elements** (like hyperlinks, or default paragraph font), by editing those styles in the reference doc.
3. Add **custom 'elements'** (styles) by adding them to the reference doc.

### Option 1. Customize default elements

1. Generate a reference doc (as mentioned in the question: `pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx`). It will have a bunch of content, representing common Pandoc components like headings and blockquotes (see picture at the end).
2. In the `Styles` menu at the top of Word, find the style you want to change and edit it to be what you'd like (I'm not sure if you can simply edit the text's style directly).

### Option 2: Customize other elements

There are more styles than the ones that appear in the reference document text and in the "Style gallery." For example, you can customize hyperlinks (e.g. color).

1. Generate a reference doc (or use the one you have from above).
2. Click the expand button in the Styles section to show the Styles pane (see below).

   [image: Styles overflow menu]
3. Find the style you want, then edit it.

Also:

- You can click an option in the dropdown beside each style to add it to the Style gallery, for easier editing.
- You can add text with that style to the document itself, if you'd like to preview what it will look like in context.

### Option 3: Add custom styles

This is probably the most relevant to the question. If you want to introduce *custom elements* beyond the default ones Pandoc provides and Word provides, you can simply add custom styles to the reference document. For example, you can create a style for highlighted text or centered text, or a style for large code blocks.

1. Generate a reference doc (or use the one you have from above).
2. Add some text to the document using the *base* style you want---the style you want to base your new custom style on. For example, if you want "normal text but highlighted," write some new text that uses the "Normal" or "Body text" style.
3. Click the dropdown in the Styles gallery.
4. Click `Create a Style`
5. Name the style, whatever you'd like.
6. Click `Modify...` and customize the style however you'd like. You can always get to this menu later by right-clicking the style in the gallery and clicking "Modify..."
7. Save the document.
8. In the text you will *convert* to docx, add `div`s and `span`s with the appropriate `custom-style` attribute whenever you want to consume it. For example, if you have a paragraph style called `Super big` and a character style called `Highlighted text`:

   ```markdown
   <div custom-style="Super big">My super big text</div>

   Normal text. <span custom-style="Highlighted text">This is highlighted</span>.
   ```

   Pandoc will apply those custom styles for you!

---

### References

- [Pandoc User's Guide - Custom Styles](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles)
- [Pandoc User's Guide - Options Affecting Specific Writers](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers)
- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4843
- [pandoc - replace heading with custom style for Word docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730436/pandoc-replace-heading-with-custom-style-for-word-docx)

---

The default reference doc:
[image: The default reference doc]

Comment: This is really nice! You might want to add a longer description on how to get the reference doc; see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/52893101/2425163

Comment: I did! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I managed to do it but it only worked for me when used with a div.

This worked for me ---> <div custom-style="Super big">My super big text</div> 

This did not work ---> <span custom-style="Highlighted text">This is highlighted</span>

Comment: @Jepeme: for paragraph styles, you must use `div`s; for character styles, you must use `span`s.

Comment: Styles can be imported from a document that already exists (for those that have one) and copied to the `custom-reference.docx`. Be sure that the style is supported in the [Pandoc User's Guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers) (it says for the best results). I found out how to do this on [MS Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/importing-styles-in-word/4cf3f144-c033-4d77-85b0-b6c0c7ba7fb5).