# Alphabetic footnote marks in pandoc

Tags: pandoc, bibliography, footnotes

I am writing a text using numeric bibliography references, i.e. a citation like [@foobar] results in a number as superscript. However, I also need to add footnotes. To distinguish between footnotes and bibliography references, I need the footnotes to be using letters of alphabet rather than numbers, i.e.

```
Here is some text [^a]

[^a]: This is a footnote
```

Should generate a superscript `a` rather than `1` as footnote reference when rendering the text. Otherwise it cannot be distinguished from a bibliography reference. Is there a way to achieve it with pandoc? I can think of a way of achieving it in LaTeX, but unfortunately the document must be generated as a Word document.

Comment: I believe this would be doable by combining https://libroediting.com/2015/06/03/how-do-i-change-the-numbering-style-of-footnotes-and-endnotes-in-word/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/70513062/2425163, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @January did you find a solution for this? And what was your idea to do this in LaTex? I have this exact same problem in LaTex and even though LaTex is correctly rendering footnote symbols as letters, pandoc is not using them.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I haven't. In the end the book I was writing was typeset with a completely different system and references were removed from the text, so that I did not need it in the end.