Using two paragraph styles in Quarto
I'm writing a text in Quarto using R to generate a Word docx document. Also I have a reference docx, document indicated at YAML format:docx:reference-doc:.
I need to use two different paragraph styles in the text. They are properly named and formatted at the ref-doc.
How can I indicate in Quarto when to change text style, i.e., when to use one or the other style?

Please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70513062/how-do-i-add-custom-formatting-to-docx-files-generated-in-pandoc especially on custom styles and <div> element. Quarto uses pandoc to word conversion, so it should work.
