# Change headline style when writing a word document using r markdown

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am using `R` and `markdown` and the `bookdown` package to write word documents.
I have a template file with very specific custom styles for the headline and the user expects the headlines to be in this specific style.

How can I change the default headline style when writing the word document. As defined here in the pandoc manual [under --reference-doc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers), The default level one headline style will be `Heading 1`. I want to use `Custom Headline 1` instead.

It has to be the different style, so just adapting the `template.docx` so the headlines look the same as the preferred style is **not an option**.

How can I change this default behaviour?

Or are there ways to later modify the created `docx` document and rename all the `Heading x` styles into `Custom Headline x`?
So far I found this SO question [pandoc - replace heading with custom style for Word docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730436/pandoc-replace-heading-with-custom-style-for-word-docx) which looks like it is doing what I am looking for. Searching further for R solutions, I found the package `pandocfilters`, but I don't see how to use it to change the style of the specific headline.

Comment: You cannot remove the built-in heading styles. See also: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm. Word uses "heading" styles, not "headline" styles. I am unsure of the significance of the term you are using. You can add an alias for the built-in styles to match your names and modify them to have your desired formatting but you indicate you must use separate styles.

Comment: There is no significance of my wording. I just need to use a specific style for headlines and figure and table captions. The table cation style can be set when using flextable package. But could find a way to set style for heading. I will try pandocfilters package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method would be to use a Lua filter. E.g., this should do it:

```lua
local heading_styles = {
  "CustomHeading1",
  "CustomHeading2",
  "CustomHeading3",
  "CustomHeading4",
  "CustomHeading5",
  "CustomHeading6",
}

function Header (el)
  local attr = el.attr
  attr.attributes['custom-style'] = heading_styles[el.level]
  return pandoc.Div(pandoc.Para(el.content), attr)
end
```

Save the code to a file `custom-headings.lua` and add this to your YAML:

```yaml
---
output:
  word_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - '--lua-filter=custom-headings.lua'
---
```

See the [R Markdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html) for details.